# RegEx pattern matcher issue

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I'm struggling with a "simple" RegEx problem. I wan't to check a sting if the pattern "BN123456" or "bn123456" is included and if so, extract it. The pattern could be in the beginning, middle or end of the string.

So I setup this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/u4oFTC/1) and this test code

```
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('[Bb][Nn][0-9]{6}');
Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(' BN123456 bn123456');

System.debug('Match?' + MyMatcher.matches());

while(MyMatcher.find()){
    System.debug('check ' + MyMatcher.group(0));
}
```

While the RegEx is working on RegEx101 it isn't in the Pattern/Matcher setting. **The Problem is, that it finds 'BN123456' only with a space infront ' BN123456'.** Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: I would recommend to check in the Stack Overflow forum for [RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) related questions.

Comment: believe me I did, but honestly I'm struggling finding the right track... but I will also have a look in the helpful link

Comment: Group zero is always the whole input. Use group(1).

Comment: @ArnoldJr. This question is about regex nuances using Salesforce-provided regex functionality. OP went through the expected steps (tuning it/testing it on regex101), so it's perfectly fine here, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your testing code erroneously uses both `matches` and `find`. Try the following:

```
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('((?:BN|bn)[0-9]{6})');
Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher('BN123456 BN');

while(MyMatcher.find()){
    System.debug('check ' + MyMatcher.group(1));
}

System.debug('Done');
```

(I didn't need to change the pattern, but I thought this was cleaner; @Oleksandr's case insensitive search is even better.)

The point is, there are quite different behaviours for `matches` and `find`, and in having applied `matches` you prevented the subsequent `find` operations from succeeding. The former, `matches`:

> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern

but you're interested in a subsequence match which is done by `find`:

> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern

These are quotes from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm#apex_System_Matcher_matches).

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick, ```matches``` was only in because I tested things, didn't recognize that this could be the cause of the issue. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make this pattern case insensitive, can use `(?i)` at the beginning of the pattern.

```
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('(?i)(BN[0-9]{6})');
Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher('1  BN1234561   bn234562.');

while(MyMatcher.find()){
    System.debug(MyMatcher.group());
}
```

---

[Matcher.matches](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm#apex_System_Matcher_matches) Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

It is not mentioned in apex doc, but mentioned in [java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) doc when it is returning a true:

> true if, and only if, the entire region sequence matches this
> matcher's pattern

that is why in this run, it is returning `false`

Comment: `(?i)(BN\\d{6})` would also do the trick. Perhaps not a great improvement in this case, but when using posix character classes like `\\p{Alnum}` or `\\p{Graph}` it can be clearer (compared to, say, `[A-Za-z0-9.,<>/?+-_=]`).